# Azure Virtual Machine Scale Set VSTS Deployment Group

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

Is it possible to have the vm's in a VMSS be in a deployment group inside of VSTS?

Could I provision a vm with the deployment group, save its disk image, and use that as the image for the vm's in the scale set? That way when a new VM is created it will already have the vsts agent on it. But, will the authentication still work against VSTS? I know it uses a PAT, I feel like there could be issues there.

Also, if new vm's "scale" up, how would they be able to get the latest version of the build? Would I have to run the Release inside of VSTS everytime the scale set scales up?

Comment: Not sure, but you can try and check the result. On the other hand, how about build the image with Deployment group's Registration script (PowerShell)? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/build-release/apps/cd/azure/deploy-azure-scaleset?view=vsts

Comment: @starianchen-MSFT that was my plan. I think I will try that, I'm just now sure how the latest build will get onto any new vm's that come online if the scaleset scales up. I guess I could add a webhook to the scale event in azure and trigger a deployment from VSTS, but that seems wrong. All my vm's would end up getting a new build if the set scales up.

Comment: How about build the image with Deployment group's Registration script (PowerShell)?

Comment: Script specified above builds entire VM image along with content. How do you do incremental deployments to already existent VMss machines. So when they boot up they register with VSTS as part of deployment group